# plot.ly candlestick graph via matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, plotly

Using the following [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_demo.html) I was able to create a candle stick graph using matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, WeekdayLocator,\
     DayLocator, MONDAY
from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc, candlestick_ohlc


# (Year, month, day) tuples suffice as args for quotes_historical_yahoo
date1 = (2004, 2, 1)
date2 = (2004, 4, 12)


mondays = WeekdayLocator(MONDAY)        # major ticks on the mondays
alldays = DayLocator()              # minor ticks on the days
weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d')  # e.g., Jan 12
dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%d')      # e.g., 12

quotes = quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc('INTC', date1, date2)
if len(quotes) == 0:
    raise SystemExit

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)
#ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dayFormatter)

#plot_day_summary(ax, quotes, ticksize=3)
candlestick_ohlc(ax, quotes, width=0.6)

ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')

plt.show()
```

And looking at plot.ly's [APIs](https://plot.ly/matplotlib/) you can publish matplotlib figures online using plot.ly.  I added the following to the above code:

```
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import plotly.plotly as py

py.sign_in('xxx', 'xxxx')
plot_url = py.plot_mpl(fig)
```

plot.ly produced the following [graph](https://plot.ly/~chriskoh/185/-line0-line1-line2-line3-line4-line5-line6-line7-line8-line9-line10-line11-line1/), if you zoom in to the graph you can see that the graph does not actually show the body of the candle stick just the upper and lower shadows.  Did I import the graph incorrectly? or does plot.ly not support candle stick graphs even if they are generated through matplotlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out as of 5/27/15 Plot.ly does not currently support candle stick.

Answer (score 2):

I actually made a request to the plot.ly devs to add candlestick chart types to the stock plot.ly package. Very surprised it still has yet to be included as a default "type"

For this use case, I was able to build my own OHLC candles by hacking together a `pandas DataFrame` with a resampled time index using 'ohlc' as the param. Only caveat is you will need a full history of all the asset's trades with timestamps for the `DataFrame` index to correctly build this type of chart:

```
newOHLC_dataframe = old_dataframe['Price'].astype(float).resample('15min', how='ohlc')
```

where the `Price` key is all your y values. This `.resample()` will build the candles and figure out max/min/first/last for the given time period all on its own. In my example above, it will give you a new `DataFrame` consisting of 15min candles. The `.astype(float)` may or may not be necessary depending on your underlying data.